# Removing group of results if total is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am using the following table to create a stacked bar chart - its quite a bit larger than this:

```
ID | Name | foodEaten | total
1  | Sam  | Burger    | 3
1  | Sam  | Pizza     | 1
1  | Sam  | Kebab     | 0
1  | Sam  | Cheesecake| 3
1  | Sam  | Sandwich  | 5
2  | Jeff | Burger    | 0
2  | Jeff | Pizza     | 0
2  | Jeff | Kebab     | 0
2  | Jeff | Cheesecake| 0
2  | Jeff | Sandwich  | 0
```

I need to find a way to remove results like Jeff. Where the entire total for what he ate is 0. I can't think of the easiest way to achieve this. I've tried grouping the entire result by Id and creating a total, but its just not happening.

If the person has eaten a total of 0 food, then he needs to be excluded. But if he hasn't, and he hasn't eaten any kebabs, as shown in my above table, this needs to be included in the result!

So the output needed is:

```
ID | Name | foodEaten | total
1  | Sam  | Burger    | 3
1  | Sam  | Pizza     | 1
1  | Sam  | Kebab     | 0
1  | Sam  | Cheesecake| 3
1  | Sam  | Sandwich  | 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the data as it appears, and not the aggregate out and then exclude:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID,
           [Name],
           foodEaten,
           total,
           SUM(total) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name]) AS nameTotal
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT ID,
       [Name],
       foodEaten,
       total
FROM CTE
WHERE nameTotal > 0;
```

Comment: this is close, but its excluding if Sam has eaten 0 burgers, which I need it to contain

Comment: @samsmith No, it doesn't [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee473a45734e8ee8ca1d44f177bdb1b1)

Comment: My bad, i used total rather than nameTotal in the "Where" Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select id,name
from tablename a
group by id,name
having sum(total)>0
```

OR

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3349ecba9a8493960f6de8f13f83f485)**

```
select * from tablename a 
where not exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.id=b.id group by id,name
having sum(total)=0)
```

Comment: The issue is, is that I need to continue to retain the format above (thanks for the edit by the way) so it would still need to have each individual line for Sam.

Comment: @samsmith, I've added another solution you can try that

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, foodEaten, sum(total) as total from <table> group by ID having sum(total) > 0
```

Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using `DELETE` with `HAVING SUM(total) = 0` will remove the group of result which their total is 0

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Id FROM TableName GROUP BY ID HAVING SUM(total) = 0)
```

or if you want to remvoe and select only the records which has sum of total is zero, then

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM TableName GROUP BY ID HAVING SUM(total) = 0)
```

Comment: I doubt the OP wants to `DELETE` their data.

Comment: @Larnu I read the title as "Removing group of results if total is 0"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE (ID , Name , foodEaten , total)
AS
(
SELECT 1  , 'Sam'  , 'Burger'    , 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1  , 'Sam'  , 'Pizza'     , 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1  , 'Sam'  , 'Kebab'     , 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1  , 'Sam'  , 'Cheesecake', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1  , 'Sam'  , 'Sandwich'  , 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 2  , 'Jeff' , 'Burger'    , 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2  , 'Jeff' , 'Pizza'     , 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2  , 'Jeff' , 'Kebab'     , 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2  , 'Jeff' , 'Cheesecake', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2  , 'Jeff' , 'Sandwich'  , 0
)
SELECT ID , Name ,SUM( total)  AS Grandtotal
FROM CTE
GROUP BY  ID , Name 
HAVING SUM( total) >0
```

Result

```
ID  Name    Grandtotal
----------------------
1   Sam         14
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `total` is never negative, then probably the most efficient method is to use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.total > 0
             );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(name, total)`.